# blocks are fluid but text doesn't resize

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have two divs, `.left` and `.right` in a `.container` div All of which widths are set in % and when I resize my browser the blocks resize too but the text `<p>` doesn't. Why is that?

Here's a link http://jsfiddle.net/TomasRR/WuNL3/10/

I have stated that .left and .right should always be 400px width when container gets 800px with this command

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .left, .right {
      width: 400px;
    }
```

however when resizing from browser's max width till 800px I want my text in .right resize too, I mean drop down on another line, so I could see the full sentence.

```
<div class="cont">
      <div class="left">
        <h1>Programming and fuss</h1>
          <h2><em>by Tomas R. </em></h2>
  <p>MY TOP 3 PAGES:</p>
          <a href="http://www.twitter.com">TWITTER</a>
          <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">WIKIPEDIA</a>
          <a href="http://www.vice.com">VICE</a>
      </div>

      <div class="right">
              <p>"An ounce of practice is generally worth more than a ton of theory." <span>E. F. Schumacher.</span></p>
      </div>  
</div> <!-- .cont -->
```

the .left doesn't interest me. How to fix the text in .right is my question.

Comment: Mr. Bojangles thank you for editing my text. It looks more solid now :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `white-space:nowrap;` entry in the css for your cont class is where the problem lies. This stops your paragraph from wrapping within the div

If you want the 2 divs to sit side by side, use `float:left;` and `float:right;`

To combat the problem with the right div dropping below the left div, you need to use `width: calc(50% - 4px);` for each div as you have borders around the divs of 1px thickness. If you adjust the border thickness you will need to adjust the pixels subtracted.

Comment: Good answer! Only improvement you might offer is a demo. And generally here on SO we edit our answers to add something like this instead of creating a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `white-space:nowrap;` entry in the css for your cont class is where the problem lies. This stops your paragraph from wrapping within the div

If you want the 2 divs to sit side by side, use `float:left;` and `float:right;`

Comment: Thank you for you answers guys. But now there is another problem when  I reduce the screen size the div falls under. I want both divs to stay on the same line. Any suggestions how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `float:left` instead and also use a container element to keep the widths as 50% and not need use `calc` to compensate for the borders

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="left">
     <div class="container">
         Foo
     </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
     <div class="container">
         Foo
     </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.cont {                                
    width:100%;
}
.right .container { border:1px solid black; }
.right {                    
    width:50%;
    height:200px;    
    float:left;
}
.left .container { border:1px solid red; }
.left {    
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    vertical-align:top;    
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WuNL3/68/)

If you want them to always take up half of the width, you just have to remove the media query that you have that sets a set width when the browser is small

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WuNL3/109/)

As a front end designer, I would recommend that at some point you use media queries to have the sections on top of each other when the screen is small so that it is responsive and readable on small screens, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/WuNL3/110/)

Comment: Thank you for you answers guys. But now there is another problem when  I reduce the screen size the div falls under. I want both divs to stay on the same line. Any suggestions how can I do that ?

Comment: @Tomas.R For what purpose? This way makes your site much more responsive to small screen sizes

Comment: The purpose is to solve this problem I have found and that's it. I'm in a learning process right now and I have found this thing I can not crack so I'm looking for help, reading articles, watching video courses. I want to work as a front end developer one day but by that time I have to know and understand everything I guess. And this is a part which I can't solve for a week now and it makes me crazy. What if that would be a task during the job ? It looks so simple and yet I can't figure how to do it.

Comment: @Tomas.R You just need to remove the media query from what I had. Updated my answer

Comment: The problem is your container is set to a % and thus will always shrink.  Your child divs are fixed widths of 400px.  So when the browser shrinks below 800, the divs have no where to go except under one another.  Give your container a min-width:800;.  This will stop the container from shrinking smaller than the fixed width of your child divs.

Comment: Jamie Collingwood you rock my world. Thank you.

Comment: And if someone else will try to do this, don't forget to add this code too: *, *:before,*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: Which answer should I select as the accepted answer ? All of you guys helped me with different bits. My heart tells me to give it to Chris so I will do that but Zach and Jamie thank you very much too.

Comment: That's quite fine, I'm in no need for more rep. Glad I could help